# Google Script - how to replace cell values in Sheet 1 by searching Sheet 2 for those values and returning correlating data from another Sheet 2 column

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Google Spreadsheet / Scripting Question:

Disclaimer: I am a beginner. Any explanation helps me tremendously.

> Long story short:
>
> 1. Worksheet 1, Column N contains comma-separated values.
> 2. Worksheet 2, Column A has all possible values that could be combined to make up the content of Worksheet 1, Column N.
> 3. Worksheet 2, Column C contains "alternative" values.
>
> I need a script that can replace all values in Worksheet 1, Column N with the "alternative" values from Worksheet 2, Column C. I need the final result to be the "alternative" values in a single, comma-separated value.
>
> I have already scripted to separate Column N values into individual values in new columns. However, I have not been able to advance further. My current splitting script appears at the bottom.

Full explanation:

"Worksheet 1" contains multiple columns, including Column "N" that contains comma-separated values. The number of rows in Sheet 1 will grow as users enter data. Currently, there are only three rows of data. Column "N" contains:

N1 has a value of "Dog, Cat, Rabbit"

N2 has a value of "Dog, Fish"

N3 has a value of "Frog, Horse, Fish"

My current Google Script gathers data from all available rows, and it then separates the comma-separated values in Column "N" into new columns, like so:

X1 has a value of "Dog", Y1 has a value of "Cat", and Z1 has a value "Rabbit"

X2 has a value of "Dog", Y2 has a value of "Fish"

X3 has a value of "Frog", Y3 has a value of "Horse", and Z3 has a value of "Fish"

"Worksheet 2" contains, in column A, all possible values that might appear above -- Dog, Cat, Rabbit, Fish, Horse, etc. So,

A1 has a value of "Dog"

A2 has a value of "Cat"

A3 has a value of "Rabbit"

A4 has a value of "Fish" -- etc. (there are 100+ total possible values).

"Worksheet 2" contains, in column C, "alternative values" (i.e., corresponding Google Calendar Resource Addresses):

C1 has a value of "domain.com_928313sdf98@resource.calendar.google.com"

C2 has a value of "domain.com_190382d0931@resource.calendar.google.com"

C3 has a value of "domain.com_295801a0181@resource.calendar.google.com"

C4 has a value of "domain.com_5s3910s1481@resource.calendar.google.com" --- etc.

I am seeking a script that, for the data in Worksheet 1, would search for the separated values in Worksheet 2 and then replace those values in Worksheet 1 with the correlating "alternative values" (i.e., Google Calendar Resource Addresses) from Worksheet 2, Column C. I then need it to concatenante the results back into a comma-separated value.

> So, I want to start with Worksheet 1, where N1 has a value of "Dog, Cat, Rabbit," and I want to get back "domain.com_928313sdf98@resource.calendar.google.com, domain.com_190382d0931@resource.calendar.google.com, domain.com_295801a0181@resource.calendar.google.com" as my final result.
>
> The script would perform this across all rows.

My Splitting Script (I am not even sure if this is the best way of handling this):

```
function mySplit() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var startcolumn = 2;
  var startrow = 2;
  var numcolumns = 500;
  var dataRange = sh.getRange(startcolumn, 1, numcolumns, 25);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var cell = sh.getRange(startcolumn + i, 15).getValues()[0];
  var sCell = cell[0].split(",");
  sh.getRange(startrow +i,26,1,sCell.length).setValues([sCell]);  
  }}
```

Comment: Why are you asking the same question in a separate post ? you just changed some details... (cal ressources are now in col C instead of B)  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in your other post, this is quite simple to do with arrays, here is a working example with your new data: see [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dG9zMzd6ZzEzY0IzX0FZQ3VUdDNuZlE&usp=sharing) (read only, make a copy to test)

```
function replaceTagsWithRessource(){ // in this example sheet, the function will replace aa with 11, bb with 22 etc...

var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
var sh2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');
var sourceCol = sh1.getRange('N2:N').getValues();
Logger.log(sourceCol)
var targetRef = sh2.getDataRange().getValues();
Logger.log(targetRef)
var newColN = []
for(var s in sourceCol){
var caltoUse = sourceCol[s][0].split(',');
   var calID = []  
  for(var n in caltoUse){
    for(var r in targetRef){
     if(caltoUse[n]==targetRef[r][0]){ calID.push(targetRef[r][2])} // get the cal ref in col 3
     }
     }
    newColN.push([calID.toString()]);
    Logger.log(newColN)
}
sh1.getRange('N2:N').setValues(newColN);// replace original values with new values (comma separated calendar IDs)
}
```

Comment: thank you, Serge. I implemented your suggestion from the last thread, but I was getting stuck. I appreciate all of your thorough help. I will give this a shot today.

Comment: With very minor tweaking (to clear cell formatting across the source and target columns), this worked nicely. I appreciate the help!

Comment: This script works well but if the sheet 1 does not contain a value it deletes the original from sheet 2. Any suggestions on how to alter the script to only replace if value is found?